# Low PPV high Sensitivity

Tags: sensitivity-specificity, confusion-matrix

The results from my analysis show a low PPV (84.73%) compared to Sensitivity (88.8%). Not sure how to interpret these statistics, need some help

```
                 Manual Process
             ----------------------
                  No           Yes
     New    No   3583          75
Automated   Yes  100           550
            -----------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interpretation depends on you data and your objective but generally, if your PPV is lower than your sensitivity, you have more false-positives than false-negatives in your data. 
Maybe you can provide more context, for example the specificity or false-positive-rate?

Sorry for not writing this as a comment but unfortunately I don't have enough reputation for that yet.

Comment: your suggestions were helpful :) , I have developed an algorithm that can automate the current existing manual review process which is very tedious, I have updated my question with a confusion matrix.